# Add separators to windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Is there any way to add separators to the Windows 7 taskbar like you can in a browser? I have a 21" monitor with enough shortcuts in the taskbar to fill the entire width. It would be visually helpful to be able to separate groups of icons (i.e. development tools, graphics tools, etc.)

Comment: +1 I had the same problem so I created a windows app back in 2009 that does **nothing** what so ever. It's 17k and has a black vertical bar as an icon. I then use several shortcuts to that exe as separators in my taskbar. I'm curious if there is another solution.

Comment: I suppose I could share it but I don't know if you'd be inclined to accept executable files from random internet strangers.

Comment: Multiple shortcuts to the same dummy exe are OK. The only thing that's annoying is that it doesn't seem you can get rid of the tooltip on the separator when you hover. Even with a " .lnk" the tooltip still shows space. Maybe I'm too fussy but it's irritating me O_o

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Creating the folders Like pinning folders to the taskbar, you need to create a folder to use as a toolbar. With this method, you can
>      create one anywhere and name it to anything: 'Programs on taskbar -
>      Microsoft Office' and 'Programs on taskbar - Abobe Master Collection
>      3' , and create them in 'categories' if you wish.
> 2. Creating the subfolders Now, in the folders you have created, create new folders for each program in that category, e.g. Office
>      Word, Office Excel, PhotoShop, Fireworks etc.
> 3. Inserting program shortcuts In the subfolders you have just put in, you just copy shortcuts of the program in there. (Just type in the
>      name of the program you want in the start menu search, right click
>      'Copy', go to the folder according to the program you are putting in
>      there, right click and select 'Paste shortcut'.)
> 4. Repeat Repeat step 3 for each program you want separated from the rest.
> 5. Unlock the taskbar.
> 6. Showing program icons in the taskbar Right click in the taskbar in an empty space, and find 'Toolbars' with the arrow next to it. Find
>      'New toolbar', and navigate to, one by one, the folder containing the
>      program. Don't open the folder, just click on it once and press the
>      'Select Folder' button. In the taskbar now should be the name of the
>      folder you have just selected. Right click and uncheck 'Show text' and
>      'Show title'. Still in the context menu, go to view, then click on
>      'Large icons'. You should now have an icon of your program in the
>      taskbar.
> 7. Repeat Repeat Step 6 for each program.

Reference:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/50438-taskbar-separate-pinned-programs.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Your right. I edited my answer.

Comment: Um... wow. That's labor-intensive for such a simple concept. Thanks for the answer, though; I'll give it a shot if I don't find an easier way.

Comment: Yeah I know. I guess the person in that article created an app that makes it easier, but I don't know how feel about downloaded things from random people.